# ASP.Net validation and javascript for update- and cancel-button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, webforms

What I want to do is to display a message during the server roundtrip of an ASP.Net WebForm. On my WebForm I have two buttons e.g. update- and cancel-button.
The message should be always displayed if either update- or cancel-button is clicked.
If the update-button is clicked there should be validated if a value is given in a TextBox.
So this is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub ButtonValidated_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Label1.Text = "ButtonValidated " & Now.ToLongTimeString & " " & TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ButtonUnvalidated_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Label1.Text = "ButtonUnvalidated " & Now.ToLongTimeString & " " & TextBox1.Text
    End Sub
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Validators and JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowValMsg(e, val) {
            dv = $get("ProgressDiv");
            var r = true;
            if (val != null) {
                r = Page_ClientValidate(val);
                if (r) {
                    dv = $get("ProgressDiv");
                    dv.style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            } else {
                dv = $get("ProgressDiv");
                dv.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
            return r;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="ValGrp" />
        <br />
        <!-- this could be the update button -->
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonJsValidated" runat="server" Text="JsValidated" OnClick="ButtonValidated_Click" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return ShowValMsg(this, &quot;ValGrp&quot;);" />
        <!-- this could be the cancel button -->
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonJsUnvalidated" runat="server" Text="JsUnvalidated" OnClick="ButtonUnvalidated_Click"  CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return ShowValMsg(this, null);" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonValidated" runat="server" Text="Validated" OnClick="ButtonValidated_Click" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="ValGrp" />
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonUnvalidated" runat="server" Text="Unvalidated" OnClick="ButtonUnvalidated_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" />
        <div id="ProgressDiv" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:300px;height:100px;width:100px;visibility:hidden;opacity: 1; z-index: auto" >Please wait ...</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If `TextBox1` is empty and I click on `ButtonValidated` and afterwards on `ButtonJsUnvalidated` it works like I want.
If `TextBox1` is empty and I click on `ButtonJsValidated` and afterwards on `ButtonJsUnvalidated` there is no server roundtrip. If I click on `ButtonJsUnvalidated` the second time it works.
So I think, there is something going wrong if I click on `ButtonJsValidated`.
All I found are discussions for one button being clicked again and validate again or how to reset validators (I have also tried without success).

Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Hannes from ppedv.de I've got the solution. My JS code now looks like this:

```js
        function ShowValMsg(e, val, msg) {
            if (msg == null) {
                if (val != null) {
                    if (Page_ClientValidate(val)) {
                        Show(e);
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    Show(e);
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (val != null) {
                    if (Page_ClientValidate(val)) {
                        if (confirm(msg)) {
                            Show(e);
                            return;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (confirm(msg)) {
                        Show(e);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function Show(e) {
            $get("ProgressDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
```